# Appirater for ios 7 deprecation of "UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque"

Tags: objective-c, ios7, deprecated

I was trying to update my app for ios 7 when I ran into the fact that in the source code for appirater: the call to set "UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque" was deprecated. Was wondering if somebody found a quick fix for it. And also I am using the latest version of Appirater.

Appirater source is [here](https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater) .

Here is the code where it throws the flag:

```
+ (id)getRootViewController {
UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
if (window.windowLevel != UIWindowLevelNormal) {
    NSArray *windows = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows];
    for(window in windows) {
        if (window.windowLevel == UIWindowLevelNormal) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

for (UIView *subView in [window subviews])
{
    UIResponder *responder = [subView nextResponder];
    if([responder isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]]) {
        return [self topMostViewController: (UIViewController *) responder];
    }
}

return nil;
}
```

Comment: Where exactly do you set in the code the 'UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque'? And also, you can use the other kinds of status bar styles Apple introduced in iOS 7.

Comment: the "return nil;" is highlighted with the error

Answer (score 1):

Note- you should return an object (id, UISomething, int) and not nil.

Especially when the method name is getRootViewController- it should return a **UIViewController** as interpreted from the name, and not a nil- at **any** case.

Comment: I am worried about breaking the code as this is a class that was not written by me. I am also pretty inexperienced and do not understand what you mean. How does UIViewController have to do with the error of UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque?

Comment: I'm talking about the method. If I'm not wrong, a method of this name and type should not return nil. As for the UIStatusBarStyle, I will do a dummy app and try it.